# What hardware can support CADisplayLink class?

Tags: iphone, hardware, vsync

I'm making a game with iPhone. I found iPhone OS 3.1 supports v-sync with CADisplayLink class. I believe v-sync is ideal solution for game graphics, I'll use this only. (no fallback to NSTimer) But SDK doc says this too; CADisplayLink is supported in only OS 3.1.

Is there a hardware model which cannot support CADisplayLink class?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a hardware model which cannot support CADisplayLink, but we've seen improvements using it in 3DAR on the following devices:

```
iPhone4 / iOS 4.1
3GS / iOS 4.0
3G / OS 3.1.2
Original / OS 3.1.3
```

I'm very happy with its performance and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the iPhone 3G and an iPod touch (1st gen), both running iOS 3.1.3. Although I'm not entirely sure if the problem is really `CADisplayLink`. I can't test it myself and the users won't send me a crash report.